# I'd like to plot the two graph together

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-datetime

Here are the 2 graphs.

[image: Text]

I'd like to plot them together(share the same x-axis) but the problem is: the X-axis of the right one has the format: Year-Month(e.g. as shown), while the left is in Year-month-day(e.g. 2020-03-23).
How can I reformat the axis? i.e. from Year-month-day --> Year and month.

Here is the date for the 2nd graph: from DataFrame function

```
               0
0     2014-11-10
1     2014-11-11
2     2014-11-12
3     2014-11-13
4     2014-11-14
...          ...
```

Here is the code for 2 graph: 1st graph

```
data = pd.read_json(r"C:\Users\taibo\Desktop\Solar_Cycle\observed-solar-cycle-indices.json", orient='records')
data2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
ndata = data2[ (data2['time-tag'] > '2014-01') & (data2['time-tag'] < '2020-12')]
x = ndata['time-tag']
y = ndata['ssn']
```

2nd graph:

```
Dose_data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\taibo\Desktop\MSL_Script\Code\Btmp.txt",sep='\s+',header=None,)
Dose_data = pd.DataFrame(Dose_data)
sol_list = Dose_data[0]
def soltodate():
    list = []
    for sols in sol_list:
        landing_date = "12/08/06" #landing date of curiosity
        landing_date_strip = datetime.strptime(landing_date, "%y/%m/%d").date()
        #print(landing_date_strip)
        x = sols*1.0275
        #x = sols to earth day
        sol_to_date = landing_date_strip + timedelta(days=x-1) # plus landing date with number of earth day
        date_list = np.array(sol_to_date)
        list.append(str(date_list))
    return(list)
Dose_date = soltodate()
Dose_date = pd.DataFrame(Dose_date)

Dose_x = new_Dosedate[0]
Dose_y = Dose_data[1]
```

Here is raw data for 1st graph:https://services.swpc.noaa.gov/json/solar-cycle/observed-solar-cycle-indices.json
2nd: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GRcjhVVg_S9PU8LJxybR-fnY7Z2kdWUw/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

That's not that difficult. Just convert the dates of the other chart to year-month.

Let's say your dates were inside a variable called dates. Then:

```
new_values = [str(a.year)+'-'+str(a.month) for a in dates]
```

Example:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

sdate = date(2019,3,22)   # start date
edate = date(2019,4,9)   # end date

dates = pd.date_range(sdate,edate-timedelta(days=1),freq='d')

new_values = [str(a.year)+'-'+str(a.month) for a in dates]

print(new_values)

['2019-3', '2019-3', '2019-3', '2019-3', '2019-3', '2019-3', '2019-3', '2019-3', '2019-3', '2019-3', '2019-4', '2019-4', '2019-4', '2019-4', '2019-4', '2019-4', '2019-4', '2019-4']
```

I hope this resolves your problem.

Once you set the date values to this new one.
Just do:

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(data1)
plt.plot(data2)
plt.show()
```

And that should do the trick I hope.

Comment: I'm getting AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'year'

Comment: The date is from a datafram: Dose_date = pd.DataFrame(Dose_date)

new_Dosedate = [str(a.year)+'-'+str(a.month) for a in (Dose_date)]

Comment: Don't make it a dataframe, just pass it as it is.

Comment: Can you print your Dose_date variable before converting it to a DataFrame and share the output here?

Comment: How do I shere it in the comment section?

Comment: ```2014-11-10, 2014-11-11```

Comment: I added the date value on the Question

Comment: I am actually trying to figure out if your dates are in string format or datetime objects. Let's do one thing. Can you by chance share these two dataframes in google drive? Just change the data but keep the dates as it is. I'll post a solution for you.

Comment: I have edited the question and added code for where both of the data from 2 graphs comes from. I am not sure what the final formats are because both data I have manipulated it from the raw data.